# Message Loss with Apache Camel Multicast

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-camel

I am performing load testing with 100K messages to my **Camel Multicast** route, where the message should get routed to **5 downstream queues(out1...out5)**, with all 5 queues receiving 100K messages.

However, in all load tests, **randomly** couple of downstream queues, do not get the exact 100K message and there is **always a loss of 2-3 messages** for some queues, but not all. This is verified by obtaining the **queueDepth** of all **out** queues.

```
from("jms://in_queue?concurrentConsumers=5&maxConcurrentConsumers=10")
.process(exg -> {
Message msg = exg.getMessage();
Map<Sttring, String> hdrs = msg.getHeaders();
String txt = msg.getBody(String.class);
exg.setOut().setHeaders(hdrs);
exg.setOut().setBody(txt);
})
.multicast()
.parallelProcessing(true)
.to("jms://out1", "jms://out2", "jms://out3", "jms://out4", "jms://out5")
.end()
```

Camel Debug logs also suggest that not all messages were sent to the few queues, as the count of sending messages for few queues exactly matches with the lost messages.

```
bash-4.2$zgrep "Sending JMS message to: queue:///out1" mylog.log | echo "sent to Out1:" `wc -l` 
Sent to Out1: 99998 
Sent to Out2: 99998 
Sent to Out3: 100000 
Sent to Out4: 99998 
Sent to Out5: 100000
```

Is there any specific configuration to be done at multicast to ensure all message reach destinations ?

Comment: In your code above, you haven't called the `multicast()` method in the Java DSL. Not sure it will make a difference, but instead of `.parallelProcessing(true)`, try `.multicast().parallelProcessing()`. If that doesn't work, try removing the `.parallelProcessing()` to see if it was running in parallel that was the problem.

Comment: Be sure to have a read of [Camel Multicast Documentation](https://camel.apache.org/components/3.21.x/eips/multicast-eip.html) as well